# Why this code´s Big-O notation is not log(log(n))

Tags: big-o

tomorrow we have midterm exam and we cant solve the Big O notation of this code:

```
for(int i =1; i<n;i=i*2)
{
   for(int j=1; j<i; j = j*2)
   {
     cout << "hello";
   }
}
```

We think it can be "log(log(n))" but it´s not true.

Comment: The number of steps of the inner loop is log(1) + log(2) + log(4) + ... log(n) which is 0+1+2+ ... + log(n) which is ...

Comment: Well, O(log log n) is **smaller** than O(log n), and the outer loop by itself definitely iterates O(log n) times, so there is no possible way it can be O(log log n). What specific reason do you have for thinking it is?

Comment: We just begin to learn Big O notation a few weeks ago and our fellow teach us a few things. We cant find the correct answer @kaya3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This loop:

> ```
> for(int i =1; i<n;i=i*2)
> ```

will execute its body with `i` in 1, 2, 4, 8, ..., up to (but not including) `i = n`. So it will execute its body O(`log n`) times.

This loop:

> ```
>     for(int j=1; j<i; j = j*2)
> ```

will execute its body with `j` in 1, 2, 4, 8, ..., up to (but not including) `i = j`. So it will execute its body O(`log(j)`) times. Because `j < n`, O(`log j`) < O(`log n`), so we can also say the `j` loop is O(`log n`).

We've established that the `i` loop performs O(`log n`) executions of the `j` loop, and the `j` loop performs O(`log n`) executions of its body. Therefore we multiply the factors to get O(`log n`) * O(`log n`) = O(`log n * log n`) = O(`log² n`) total executions of the `j` loop's body.

Note that `log² n` is the mathematician's way of writing `(log n)²`. It is **not** the same as `log log n`.

Answer (score 0):

If we make a graphic table, we can see the answer is O(n^2):

[image: Graphic Table of Code]

Comment: It's not O(n^2). You have mixed up your x and y axes in your graph.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).